# cURL request always 404's no matter what I do

Tags: curl, jira

My cURL commands continuously return a 404 Not Found no matter what I do to change the command. My latest iteration...

```
curl -D- -u user:pass(these are filled in) -X GET https://jira.some-company.net/rest/api/2/issues/search?jql=project=QABL
```

I've tried searching different items, having the "-H "Content-Type: application/json"" and "-H "Authorization: Basic user:pass(encrypted in b64)"" and changing from GET to POST and a lot of other things. It refuses to connect except for when I ask for permissions, but it shows that I have full admin privileges. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: I assume you've tried your URL in a browser and get the proper results, so this is just a matter of figuring out why cURL is failing?

Comment: you should better url-encode the `jql` value as in: `.../search?jql=project%3DQABL`

Comment: Turns out it was prompted by captcha because of failed logins before. Manually logging in fixed it.